# UITextView character wrap but not word wrap

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UITextView that I would like to disable word wrap on but keep character wrapping enabled.

Basically I would like to have a long string 200+ characters that still wraps in the textview but prevents word recognition and/or word wrap.  Is this possible and if so can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with a stock `UITextView`, because there is no `lineBreakMode` property in its public API. If you don't need the text to be editable, you could look into other solutions such as a `UILabel` or Core Text. Getting this behavior in an editable control is possible, but will probably be a pretty hard slog.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
NSMutableAttributedString *att=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:str];
NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
[att addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:range];
```

Comment: Close, but I'm pretty sure Dan wants `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping`.